# long running script blocks other things

Tags: mysql

I am using the MySQL command line client to run some very long running external sql files.  The command line client can be occupied for several hours at a time, so that I am not able to do other work with the database using the command line client.

Some of my long running scripts load data from external sources.  Other long running scripts do transformations of existing tables, taking a couple tables as inputs and creating a new tables with millions of new rows.

Is there some way that I can have the long running script work in the background so that I can perform other commands while the long running script is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are problably using the source command in mysql's command line... This is mainly supposed to output the results so it usually takes a while...

Have you tried this?

```
mysql -u {username} -p {password} {databasename} < file_name.sql
```

Comment: where do I enter the password?  this is a password protected database.

Comment: Check out the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-batch-commands.html

Comment: it'll prompt you for the password